# UINavigationController: Clean interactive transition to view controller without navigation bar?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller navigation hierarchy where only the top view controller hides has its navigation bar hidden.  Normal pushing/popping is fine and works as expected.  However, when the pop is *interactive* (drag-to-pop), the top opaque bar doesn't disappear until the transition is finished.  I've implemented the logic in the following delegate call:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if( [viewController isKindOfClass:[MyTopViewController class]] == YES ) {

        id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> transitionCoordinator = viewController.transitionCoordinator;

        if( transitionCoordinator != nil && transitionCoordinator.initiallyInteractive == YES ) {
            [transitionCoordinator notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {

                if( context.isCancelled == YES ) {
                    return;
                }

                [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
            }];
        } else {
            [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
        }

    } else {
        [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    }
}
```

I've already attempted numerous variations of this, but each one has had various issues with interactive transitions, especially if the transition is canceled mid-way.  What's the best way to approach this?